# jdbc spring security, apache commons dbcp

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-security, apache-commons-dbcp

In a Spring Security, I defined a jdbc auth manager:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="securityDataSource"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="securityDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/mydb"/>
    ... user and password props ...
</bean>
```

At this point I've discovered that I need Jakarta Commons DBCP. 
I've added commons-dbcp-1.4, i get the following exception:

```
...java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/KeyedObjectPoolFactory
```

This path actually isn't included in commons dbcp 1.4. 
What am I missing again?

EDITED
Ok, added the dependency to common pool, it works because with the right credentials I no more get the "bad credentials" page.
But I get an HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied. 
Seems like my user is authenticated , but isn't authorized. 
Any idea...? :-) 

My http element is:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
</security:http>
```

and I have a "test" user that is bind to the "USER" role in the "authorities" table.

thanks

Comment: I would suggest stepping through the source (via debug), specifically the JdbcDaoImpl class and see where it takes you and what is generating the 403 (it's in one of the Filters, but I cannot remember which off the top of my head).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Commons DBCP relies on the Commons Pools libraries, because of this, you actually need to download the commons-pool jar files, and include them in your path.

[Commons Pool Downloads](http://commons.apache.org/pool/downloads.html)

You may also need to download the commons-collections package, too.

Comment: OK. Is there a way to debug what happens on db? the query that are issued to the db?

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with Postgres, however, I'm sure they have some sort of logging that you should be able to turn on. From your side you can get the source of Commons DBCP and see what's sent across by using Eclipse or Netbeans or the like. But, it probably wont have the complete statement (mostly likely a prepared statement that Spring Security generates and an object that contains all the param values).

Comment: I've EDITED the question, i've a little further prolbem :-)

Answer (score 2):

The jar file commons-dbcp-1.4 does not contain the class `org.apache.commons.pool.keyedobjectpoolfactory`
You need to add another jar to your project classpath - commons-pool-1.4. 
You can download commons-pool-1.4 from here http://commons.apache.org/pool/download_pool.cgi

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your test user's authority to ROLE_USER.

Comment: Ok, using ROLE_USER works fine. I misunderstood the reference that talks of ROLE_ as it was a sort of "keyword". Now I'm going back to the reference to utry nderstand what are all those strange "ROLE_" discussions about.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget you'll also need the Postgre JDBC drivers, just in case you hadn't included those already.

Comment: "commons" are use throughout the spring reference; but sometimes it's said that in production you should use jndi. Is it just an advice or something stronger?