# Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am getting this exception when trying to start my spring MVC hibernate app.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/mysql_persistence_info.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1235)
```

My /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/mysql_persistence_info.xml is

```
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/MyrDB"/>
    <property name="username" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="user"/>
    <!-- connection pooling details -->
    <property name="initialSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="5"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
    <!--   all the annotation entity classes -->
    </list>
    </property>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

I have all jar files required in classapath.
I am using STS.

I have commons-dbcp.jar and all the rest of the jar files too.

Comment: It is not enough to have the jars in STS / eclipse classpath - they should be in the web-inf\lib folder - if you are trying to run it as a webapp.

Comment: With STS I don't know really know where the web-inf/lib path is. I looked in the web app directory and there is no web-inf/lib folder.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please make sure that commons-dbcp-1.4.jar file is inside of your lib folder. you should copy past it in eclipse.

See this image

[image]

Comment: I had to add common-pools.jar and spring.jar. In addition I had to add a web-inf/lib folder and pull it in. I would think STS would have that auto created but it does not seem it was doing it.

Comment: All jars supposed to be there, but for your question org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource located inside of commons-dbcp-1.x.jar

Comment: For those who use maven : 
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: had a similar issue - reason: I was using <version>20030825.183949</version>. I changed it to <version>1.4</version> and I was sorted.

Answer (score 4):

For me, just adding **commons-dbcp-1.4.jar** to my classpath did not work. Had to add **commons-pool-1.6.jar** as well.
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6509244/2056646) describes the reason. There is a download link too in that post.

Answer (score 0):

did a clean directory of tomcat from eclipse and it worked without downloading the jar file